# How to make simple calculator using Functions in C?

Tags: c, calculator

I have tried making simple calculator in C.
but it's not working could anyone please tell me the problem with solution.
I am new in programming, so pardon for any silly mistake. 
     Is there any problem of parameters, as I have taken 3 input but in parameters of function I have used 2 only.
Divide Function is not working well.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
int fun1(int *a,int *b);
int fun2(int *c,int *d);
int fun3(int *e,int *f);
int fun4(int *g,int *h);
int main()
{
    int i,k;
    char j;
    scanf("%d%c%d",&i,&j,&k);
    switch(j)
    {
        case '/':
            fun1(&i,&k);
            break ;
        case '*':
            fun2(&i,&k);
            break ;
        case '+':
            fun3(&i,&k);
            break ;
        case '-':
            fun4(&i,&k);
            break ; 
        default:
            printf("ERROR");
    }
    getch();
    return 0;   
}
fun1(int *a,int *b)
{
    float divide;
    float A=*a,B=*b;
    if(A%B==0)
    {
        divide=A/B;
        printf("= %.0f",divide);
    }
    else
    {
        divide=A/B;
        printf("= %.2f",divide);
    }
}
fun2(int *c,int *d)
{
    int multiply,C=*c,D=*d;
    multiply=C*D;
    printf("= %d",multiply);
}
fun3(int *e,int *f)
{
    int add,E=*e,F=*f;
    add=E+F;
    printf("= %d",add);
}
fun4(int *g,int *h)
{
    int subtract;
    int G=*g,H=*h;
    subtract=G-H;
    printf("= %d",subtract);
}
```

Comment: What is the error that you get?

Comment: "but it's not working" - pardon the obvious, but if it were working, you wouldn't be here. What **is** it doing, and how is that different than what you're expecting? "I'm expecting it to work, and it doesn't" is not an option here. Related: `divide=A/B;` perform integer division, saving the result to a `float` *afterward*. I can confidently say it is highly *unlikely* that is what you desire. And why you're passing those arguments by address remains a mystery.

Comment: You probbaly want to replace all `int`s by `float`s or `double`s in order to be able to use floating point numbers.

Comment: This shouldn't even compile, `fun1(int *a,int *b)` with no return type declared is not valid C. You need to get a modern compiler or learn how to configure your current one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In `fun1` you have `divide = A/B`.  `A` and `B` are of type `int`, so `A/B` will be of type `int`, loosing any fractional part.  This integer is then assigned to `divide` which is type float, at this point the integer result of the division is converted to a float.

Try: `divide = (float) A / (float) B` instead.

The other points made about your code are all good, and should also be addressed.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the value that the functions return to **void** because they don't return anything.

```
void fun1(int *a,int *b);
void fun2(int *c,int *d);
void fun3(int *e,int *f);
void fun4(int *g,int *h);
```

Comment: @SouravGhosh so if you don't write them right - the main function won't know them  - and can't use them!

Answer (score 0):

you code is working, but need some error checking:
1. check for correct input:

```
if (scanf("%d%c%d", &i, &j, &k) != 3){
    printf("incorrect input\n");
    return 1; //err
}
```

and check for divide by zero and floating point percisions.
2.  use good name for function: Add Sub ...
3. do not pass pointer when it is not needed.
4. use `#include<stdint.h>' and`int32_t` or 'int64_t' ... when you do not need platform dependent types.
5. do not use function return type when you do not need it.

if your code is just to print like your sample, you may write like this:

```
#include<stdint.h>
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int32_t i, k;
    char j;
    if (scanf("%d%c%d", &i, &j, &k) != 3){
        printf("incorrect input\n");
        return 1; //err
    }
    switch (j)
    {
    case '/':
        if (k == 0)printf("Divide by 0\n");else printf("%.2f\n", i / (float)k);
        break;
    case '*':
        printf("%d\n", i*k);
        break;
    case '+':
        printf("%d\n", i + k);
        break;
    case '-':
        printf("%d\n", i - k);
        break;
    default:
        printf("incorrect input\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

i hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You roughly want this, but there is still a lot of room for improvement (e.g: variable names other than a,b,c,i,j,k, function names other then fun1, fun2, etc., functions returning values instead of printing results, error checking, replacing `int`s by `float`, ...) :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>

void fun1(int a, int b);
void fun2(int c, int d);
void fun3(int e, int f);
void fun4(int g, int h);

int main()
{
    int i,k;
    char j;
    scanf("%d%c%d",&i ,&j, &k);

    switch(j)
    {
        case '/':
            fun1(i, k);
            break ;
        case '*':
            fun2(i, k);
            break ;
        case '+':
            fun3(i, k);
            break ;
        case '-':
            fun4(i, k);
            break ; 
        default:
            printf("ERROR");
            break;
    }

    getch();
    return 0;   
}

void fun1(int a, int b)
{
    printf("%d",a / b);
}

void fun2(int c,int d)
{
    printf("%d",c * d);
}

void fun3(int e, int f)
{
    printf("%d",e-f);
}

void fun4(int g,int h)
{
    printf("%d",g-h);
}
```